# Warning when converting between two arraylists holding objects of the same types

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

In class Node I got

```
private ArrayList<Node> neighbors;

public ArrayList<Node> getNeighbors() {
    return this.neighbors;
}
```

In class Graph I got

```
public void foo(Node first) {
    ArrayList<Node> firstNeighbors = first.getNeighbors();
    ...
}
```

Compiling this gives me the warning

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
ArrayList<Node> firstNeighbors = first.getNeighbors();
required: ArrayList<Node>
found:    ArrayList
```

Does anyone see the error here?

Comment: The error shows `first.getNeihbors` but you aren't showing as the code with first, you are showing us code with `test.getNeighbors`

Comment: Sorry guys, I accidentally changed the name of first to test. Also, Class A is Node. Now it is edited as in my source code.

Comment: how are you compiling the code? within an ide, or directly with javac?

Comment: javac -Xlint:unchecked

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown is not from the code you posted,

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion ArrayList
>   firstNeighbors = first.getNeighbors();

You need to check the `first` object. the object should be of `class A` or should be the subclass of it get the arraylist from the `getNeighbors()` method.

You could probably do ,

```
classA obj= new ClassA();
List<Node> firstNeighbors = obj.getNeighbors();
```

to get the values from the method and pass to the `list`

Comment: this is not a solution, so it should be a comment

Comment: And it seems clear that he renamed the 'first' object to 'test' for the purpose of this question, then failed to update the error message. Perhaps because he didn't understand the error. I'm pretty sure they're the same variable.